# discrete probability distribution vs finite sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a discrete probability distribution $f$ over a countable set $E$ such that: there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any finite set $F\subseteq E$ we have $f(F)< 1-\epsilon$.

I don't think it is possible but I don't see any good argument why. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible because $\Bbb{N} = \bigcup_{n} \{ 1, \dots , n \}$, hence $\lim_n f( \{ 1, \dots , n \} ) = f( \Bbb{N} ) = 1$.

Comment: @Crostul of course. thank you. sorry it was a trivial question. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Crostul for the comment.

It is not possible because $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_n\{1,\dots,n\}$ thus $\lim_n f(\{1,\dots,n\})=f(\mathbb{N})=1$.